# pig -version Shows error

Tags: command-line, java, environment-variables, jdk, hadoop

```
deepak@deepak-Linux:~$ pig -version
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 166: /usr//bin/java: No such file or directory

deepak@deepak-Linux:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk-9.0.1

deepak@deepak-Linux:~$ echo #HADOOP_HOME
```

`HADOOP_HOME` is empty but I've Set Path in `~/.bashrc`.

**My `~/.bashrc`:**

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop  
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin  
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME  
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME  
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME  
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME  
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native  
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin  
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME 

export PIG_HOME=/home/deepak/pig  
export PATH=$PATH:/home/deepak/pig/bin  
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME  

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-9.0.1  
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

How to fix this error.. Thanks for the solution in advance.

Comment: What's the output of `which java`? How did you install JDK 9 ad Pig?

Comment: I re-installed java 8 using terminal. Now its working fine.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)